# Retrieve Strapi data using web client spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, webclient, strapi

I am trying to retrieve the data from strapi latest versio 4 using webclient in spring boot.

The data is one level deeper, as per document following URL will give data.

/api/customer?filters[state][$eq]=karnataka&populate=%2A

/api/customer?filters[state][$eq]=karnataka&populate=* -> This will work for webclient

I tried to use webclient but its not working, if http client then it works.

Below pasted both the approaches, http one works but webclient doesnt give next level data at all

Can u please help me with this?

```
HttpRequest request =
          HttpRequest.newBuilder().GET().uri(URI.create(urlToUse)).build();
          java.net.http.HttpClient client =
          java.net.http.HttpClient.newBuilder().build(); HttpResponse<String> response
          = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
          output= new ObjectMapper()
          .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
          .readValue(response.body(), Customer.class);


 Mono<String> mon = webClient.get()
        .uri(urlToUse)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class);
        
        String resp =   mon.block(Duration.ofMillis(cmsConfig.getTimeOut()));
        
        output= new ObjectMapper()
              .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
              .readValue(resp, Customer.class);
```

Update on observation:

I did capture packets using wireshark:

With webclient packet i can see request as below:

?filters%5Bstate%5D%5B$eq%5D=karnataka&populate=%252A

With httpclient packet:

?filters[state][$eq]=Karnataka&populate=%2A

%25 is appended to 2A, as % ASCII is %25, how to avoid it? Is this causing an issue?

Comment: Why do you convert (json) to String (in between)? Tried `Mono<Customer>...` ? (without some "local" object mapper ..relying on spring-boot's);)

Comment: @xerx593 I tried as below:      customer = webClient.get()
                    .uri(urlToUse)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Customer>() {
                    })
                    .block(Duration.ofMillis(cmsConfig.getTimeOut()));

Comment: @xerx593, updated the question with more details.

Comment: `%2A == urlEncode("*")` ... `%252A == urlEncode(urlEncode("*"))`!(?)

Comment: Finally i fixed it as : webClient.get()
                    .uri(URI.create(urlToUse))